# Confirmation for Url.Action in razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I am using an edit button inside a gridview. I want a confirmation button before calling to the action?

```
grid.Column("","",format:@<text>@if(!item.IsBookPublished)
{
 <text> <a href='@Url.Action("EditBookByID","Books", new {BookID = @item.BookDetailsID, CreatedBy = @item.UserID , onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit?')" })'>Edit</a></text>
 }
 </text>
```

However the onclick property is not evaluating, instead it is passing as a parameter. How can I achieve confirmation?

Comment: You may use jQuery to manage onclick event to href. Inside `<a> tag you can store bookID in attribute. JavaScript event function simply read this, show confirm dialog and redirect to action after confirmation.

Comment: Thanks Robert got it worked, miss placed the onclick inside the object attributes (please see Darins and Ryan's answers). However would like to confirm that, in chrome and all after few clicks we can disable alerts. What happens after that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've placed it at the wrong place. Right now you've passed it as parameter to the Url.Action helper, whereas it should be a separate attribute, the same way you defined the href attribute:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("EditBookByID", "Books", new { bookID = item.BookDetailsID, CreatedBy = item.UserID })" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit?')">Edit</a>
```

By the way you should consider using helpers for that:

```
grid.Column("", "", format:
    @<text>
        @if(!item.IsBookPublished)
        {
            Html.ActionLink(
                "Edit", 
                "EditBookByID", 
                "Books",
                new { bookID = @item.BookDetailsID },
                new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit?')" }
            )
        }
    </text>
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Darin :) Completely missed it !!

Comment: Thanks that worked :) Can you tell me why we should need this helpers? Is there any advantages over anchor tags?

Comment: Yes, there are many advantages: server side helpers will take care of properly encoding all data.

Comment: Hi Darin one more question, if I require this url.Action in a button, how can I do the confirmation. For Example : `<input style="float:left" type="button" title="Back to Book List" value="Back to Book List" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditBookByID", "Books", new { bookID = item.BookDetailsID, CreatedBy = item.UserID })'" />`

Comment: Like this: `<input style="float:left" type="button" title="Back to Book List" value="Back to Book List" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit?')) { window.location.href='@Url.Action("EditBookByID", "Books", new { bookID = item.BookDetailsID, CreatedBy = item.UserID })'; }" />`.

Comment: But that's absolutely wrong semantic markup. You should not use a button for something that redirects. You should use an anchor.

Answer (score 5):

By putting the 'onclick' inside the Url.Action helper, you're *telling* it to translate it as a URL parameter.

What you want to do instead is put the onclick outside the helper like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("EditBookByID","Books", new {BookID = @item.BookDetailsID, CreatedBy = @item.UserID  })' onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to Edit?')">
    Edit
<a>
```